# Does the series $1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}+\cdots $ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}+\cdots $ **converge or diverge**?

Comment: @thanasissdr the signs do not alternate here.

Comment: You could say the signs alternate: you have the positive term $1+\frac12$, then the negative term $-\frac13$, then the positive term $\frac14+\frac15$, etc.  But the terms do not get smaller in absolute value: the positive term, consisting of two terms, is bigger in absolute value than the one before it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes -- my point was that the alternating series criterion did not apply here, which is what thanasissdr seemed to imply. The signs alternate if one groups the terms, but then the monotone-non-increasing assumption fails. And if one does not group the terms, then the signs do not alternate.

Comment: Funfact: If you change the numerator in the negative terms from $-1$ to $-2$ then it converges to $\log(3)$.

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}-\frac{1}{3n+3}> \frac{1}{3n+1}$$

So no.

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
& \underbrace{1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}}_{\ge 1} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}}_{\ge 1/4} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}}_{\ge 1/7} + \underbrace{\frac 1 {10} + \frac 1 {11} - \frac 1 {12}}_{\ge 1/10} + \cdots \\[10pt]
\ge {} & 1 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 7 + \frac 1 {10} + \frac 1 {13} + \cdots \\[10pt]
\ge {} & \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 6 + \frac 19 + \frac 1 {12} + \frac 1 {15} + \cdots \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 3 \left( 1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 5 + \cdots \right) = \infty.
\end{align}